# Postfix pipe alias not getting run

Tags: bash, email, archlinux, postfix-mta

I want to run a script that executes whenever anyone sends a mail to a specific mailbox on my ArchLinux server. From what I've read, I need Postfix and an `alias` file for that, so that's what I installed. However, my script is not getting run (the tempfiles aren't being created, see the script below), even though Postfix says it delivered to it (see syslog below). Hostnames and account names have been redacted, as have all comment lines. I whitelisted Microsoft and Gmail, those IPs I kept here as well.

My `/etc/postfix/aliases`:

```
root: bence98
MAILER-DAEMON:  postmaster
postmaster:     root
# ... a whole bunch of default mappings to `root`
mymbox: |/usr/local/bin/my-script
```

My `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
compatibility_level = 3.8
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/bin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/bin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
# setting this didn't help either
# scriptaccount is a normal user
default_privs = scriptaccount
# this is my correct public DNS
myhostname = my.public.domain.tld
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 <local subnet> [::1]/128 [fe80::]/64 40.107.0.0/16 209.85.128.0/17
alias_database = $alias_maps
```

My `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
```

`/usr/local/bin/my-script`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Execed as $USER" >/tmp/mail.log
cat >/tmp/incoming.eml
```

Output to syslog:

```
postfix/qmgr[3476413]: 08571843540: from=<bence98@mymailprovider.tld>, size=7662, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/local[3476483]: 08571843540: to=<mymbox@my.public.domain.tld>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.05/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/local/bin/my-script)
postfix/qmgr[3476413]: 08571843540: removed
postfix/smtpd[3476466]: disconnect from mail-db3eur04on2105.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.107.6.105] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 bdat=1 quit=1 commands=5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, even though all config files said *not* to chroot the `local` daemon, systemd decided to chroot it to `/tmp/systemd-private-*-postfix.service-*/`. Therein, I found my files.